# What is arrCols in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

Stupid question, but....I've noticed different  sub macros use it. There's even a confusing reference to Collections when I Google it (where *arrCols* itself isn't at all [mentioned](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/#What_is_a_Collection)).

I'm trying to figure out what it precisely does for my formula..my formula is very big, but here is the following that mentions arrCols:

```
 Dim arrCols() As Integer
```

(other lines of code appear here, and then the next bunch as below:)

```
 Next I
'ReDim arrCols(wsResult.Columns.Count)

'For I = 0 To UBound(arrCols)
'    arrCols(I) = I + 1
'Next I
```

Would anyone know what these means in plain English?  This is indeed part of a large sub macro, which I did not write but am now trying to debug (Stepping through doesn't help/ tell me anything). I know *Dim* means "declare" and *Next I* indicates that it's the start of the next loop of the macro. There are no other references to arrCols after the first *Dim*

Thanks so much,

Comment: arrCols is short for an `Array` of `Columns`

Comment: It's a common convention to name a variable, but not a standard of the language. It's common enough that you'll see many developers use that name (and others).

Comment: Thank yo so much @dwirony, this is great!

Comment: Thank you @PeterT ...interesting!

Answer (score 7):

`arrCols()` is declared as an array of integers, however, it is not yet given a size.

The `ReDim` statement re-dimensions the array to its size.

In VB, arrays are declared with round brackets. That is confusing because it sometimes looks like a function. Most other languages use the square brackets for arrays, like `int myArray[30];` in C.

Comment: Thank you @Paul-Ogilvie! This is very helpful

Comment: I omitted the ' to the bigger  lines of code by mistake (fixing that now), but now I understand that the person who wrote this started to declare an array of variables then decided not to use it, since the bigger chunk I shared is commented out.

Comment: Also worth pointing out as can't see elsewhere in answers or comments, is that the name `arrCols` was decided by the coder.  It could just as easily be `Dim MyBigFatArrayOfColumns() as Integer` or as more commonly seen `Dim x() as Integer` which means nothing - a good name helps you remember why you created the variable in the first place.

Comment: To further @DarrenBartrup-Cook's point a good name like `Dim CheckColumns() as Integer` or `Dim BondIssuanceColumns() as Integer` or `Dim ColumnsWithCodes() as Integer` is much more descriptive and useful then `Dim arrCols() as Integer`. The aforementioned names tell someone (mostly others or you, the coder, after months away from the code) **what** and **why** the code is doing. `arr` is superflous because the `()` is already there. And well, `Cols` is just `Columns`. Its also especially helpful if you place the variable dimension *very close* to where you use the variable.

Comment: Yes I've seen and de-coded other Dim statements....I just noticed also that particularly arrCols is used in other places too, I've seen them in other macros posted to the Internet, even on StackOverflow. My colleague who left did not write a good macro I think, lol, it's driving me crazy ...Thank you for the helpful comments @DarrenBartrup-Cook and @scott-holtzman!!

Answer (score 0):

`arrCols` is a user defined array variable.

`Redim` Reallocates storage space for an array variable.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/redim-statement